# Can the distribution over the squared moduli of the 'probabilities' defined by an RBM with complex weights be written as an RBM with real weights?

Tags: machine-learning

I posted this question originally on the math boards, but figured it would be better suited here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2203967/can-the-distribution-over-the-squared-moduli-of-the-probabilities-defined-by-a

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.  We want you to pick only one site to post on.  If you're not sure which site is best, you could drop by both sites chat rooms, or look around at other questions asked and answered on these sites.  Thank you!